# Subprocess not defined in a simple python scrip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I am new to scene and I have made a simple python script that should play a video

```
import os
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from subprocess import Popen

movies = "revolving.mp4"
playingmovie = ["omxplayer","-b","/home/pi/Videos/"+movies]
omxc = Popen(playingmovie, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

Which gives off the following error:

```
File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
omxc = Popen(playingmovie, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

I have tried to do some research on the subject but found no answer to my problem. In said research, I found that I should run the command

```
sudo find / | grep subprocess
```

Which returns

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/subprocess.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/__pycache__/base_subprocess.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/__pycache__/subprocess.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/subprocess.py
/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/__pycache__/subprocess.pypy-41.pyc
/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/subprocess.py
/usr/lib/pypy/lib_pypy/__pycache__/_subprocess.pypy-41.pyc
/usr/lib/pypy/lib_pypy/_subprocess.py
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `subprocess` but you only imported one class from subprocess package.

You could import whole `subprocess` and use it like:

```
import os
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import subprocess

movies = "revolving.mp4"
playingmovie = ["omxplayer","-b","/home/pi/Videos/"+movies]
omxc = subprocess.Popen(playingmovie, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

Comment: Now the error became
File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    omxc = Popen(playingmovie, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
NameError: name 'Popen' is not defined

Comment: copy my code - it should be subprocess.Popen not Popen.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I missed that detail. Now it works!